# fscanf not working in C while reading char #

Tags: c, string, file, char, scanf

I have to read text file with some football matches seperated with # and \n.
I tried this:

```
char *pr;
char *dr;
char *re;
int f;

ul=fopen("nogomet.txt","r");

f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",pr);
while (f!=EOF){
    printf("pr-%s\n",pr);

    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",dr);
    printf("dr-%s\n",dr);

    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^\n]\n",re);
    printf("re-%s\n",re);

    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",pr);
}
```

But it chrashes when it gets at:

```
    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",dr);
```

Can someone help me please?
Am I using fscanf wrong?

input file is like this:

```
Carlton Blues (Melbourne)#Geelong Cats (Geelong)#3:0
Collingwood Magpies (Melbourne)#Melbourne Demons (Melbourne)#5:3
```

...and so on...

Comment: what are dr & pr and what do they contain?

Comment: Edited. Just char *. They have to contain "string" of first and second team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not allocated any space for pr and dr. The scanf needs to read data to a buffer.

here's an example from the  [C++ Reference for fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

```
/* fscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];  // << ---------- allocated some space.
  float f;
  FILE * pFile;

  pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w+");
  fprintf (pFile, "%f %s", 3.1416, "PI");
  rewind (pFile);
  fscanf (pFile, "%f", &f);
  fscanf (pFile, "%s", str);  // <<--------------------
  fclose (pFile);
  printf ("I have read: %f and %s \n",f,str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!

I've been awake 18 hours straight, so I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Preet is spot on.

Also if you feel a bit uneasy about having one fscanf() outside of the loop, you can do this:

```
char pr[500];
char dr[500];
char re[500];

int f;

while (1){
    //PR
    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",pr);
    if (f==EOF)
        break;
    printf("pr-%s\n",pr);

    //DR
    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^#]#",dr);
      //we can also check f here
    printf("dr-%s\n",dr);

    //RE
    f=fscanf(ul,"%[^\n]\n",re);
      //we can also check f here
    printf("re-%s\n",re);
}
```

will print

```
pr-Carlton Blues (Melbourne)
dr-Geelong Cats (Geelong)
re-3:0
pr-Collingwood Magpies (Melbourne)
dr-Melbourne Demons (Melbourne)
re-5:3
```